How to rotate/flip a toggle button control?
I created a vertical/horizontal property.  if the variable _isVertical false then the control stays horizontal by default.  if i set the _isVertical to true the control with all drawings should rotate/flip by degrees.
inherit from a CheckBox
public class ToggleButton : CheckBox
{
private bool _isVertical = false;

[Category("Custom Appearance")]
public bool IsVertical
{
    get => _isVertical;
    set
    {
        _isVertical = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

in the paint:
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    base.OnPaint(pevent);
    Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    // Handle rotation if vertical
    if (_isVertical)
    {
        g.TranslateTransform(Width / 2, Height / 2);
        g.RotateTransform(90);
        g.TranslateTransform(-Width / 2, -Height / 2);
    }

    // Draw the background
    Rectangle backgroundRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(currentBackColor), backgroundRect);

    // Draw the toggle
    int toggleSize = Math.Min(Width, Height) - 4; // Toggle size
    int toggleX = (int)currentPosition;
    int toggleY = (Height - toggleSize) / 2; // Center vertically
    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(currentToggleColor), toggleX, toggleY, toggleSize, toggleSize);

    // Reset transformations if vertical
    if (_isVertical)
    {
        g.ResetTransform();
    }

    // Optional: Draw border
    using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1))
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(borderPen, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
    }
}

the results:
when the variable _isVertical is false:
control is horizontal
when i set the variable _isVertical to true then i get this:
vertical
when it's vertical the whole graphics in the control change to square and the control itself still horizontal state.
i tried to rotate/flip the control in the paint but it's not working as i wanted.

What's your expected effect?

The main problem is that you cannot draw outside of the bounds of the control. So, if the control is oriented horizontally, i.e. Width is much greater than Height, then you cannot change that by drawing something vertical on it. You will have to swap the Width and Height values themselves.
Assuming that this horizontal versus vertical decision is made at design time and not dynamically at runtime, you would have to size the control manually in the designer. Then you can determine whether it is vertical or not like this:
bool isVertical = Height > Width;

I would not rotate anything but instead calculate the x- and y-coordinates accordingly.
In the example below I also changed a couple of things.
I added a ToggleColor property to allow the section of a color in the designer. As BackColor I take the current BackColor of the control, so that it can be set it in the designer as well.
To enable resizing the Control, AutoSize must be false. I set it in OnParentChanged. This happens when you drop the control on the form.
public class ToggleButton : CheckBox
{
    private Color _toggleColor = Color.White;
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
     Category("Appearance")]
    public Color ToggleColor
    {
        get => _toggleColor;
        set {
            _toggleColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        AutoSize = false; // Allows manual resize
        if (BackColor == Parent?.BackColor) {
            // Otherwise it will have the same color as the Form
            BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        int toggleSize = Math.Min(Width, Height) - 5;
        bool isVertical = Height > Width;
        int toggleX, toggleY;
        if (isVertical) {
            toggleX = 2;
            // On position is at the top, Off position at the bottom
            toggleY = Checked ? 2 : Height - toggleSize - 3;
        } else {
            toggleX = Checked ? Width - toggleSize - 3 : 2;
            toggleY = 2;
        }

        Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        // Draw the background
        g.Clear(BackColor); // Use the current BackColor of the control

        using var toggleBrush = new SolidBrush(ToggleColor);
        g.FillEllipse(toggleBrush, toggleX, toggleY, toggleSize, toggleSize);
    }
}


Note: using var was introduced in C# 8.0. If you are using an older C# version, you can use the more verbose using-statement instead.
